# Can't connect to Freenas over public IP Adress

Tags: network-attached-storage, truenas

I have built a freenas server. It's behind a router and i a modified a NAT setting that allowed the server to be assigned with the router's public IP adress.

Now, i get an error when I connect to it over this IP adress in a system outside the local network.

I can connect and use it properly when I use it's local hostname in the local network.

Any explanations?

IP: 86.157.45.123

Windows gives the error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" when I try to map a folder to `\\86.157.45.123\data`.

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As port 445 is not in the list below, it seems that samba is not listening on your public IP address (or 0.0.0.0 for that matter) or that port 445 is filtered.
Windows falls back to WebDAV IIRC, but that seems not to be enabled too.

```
% nmap -F  86.157.45.123

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-04 12:12 CET
Nmap scan report for host86-157-45-123.range86-157.btcentralplus.com (86.157.45.123)
Host is up (0.11s latency).
Not shown: 70 filtered ports, 26 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
111/tcp open  rpcbind
443/tcp open  https

% nmap -p445 86.157.45.123

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-04 12:15 CET
Nmap scan report for host86-157-45-123.range86-157.btcentralplus.com (86.157.45.123)
Host is up (0.068s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
```

Comment: Now, how i do open port 445. Considering that I'm new to this, how do i fix the problem?

Comment: Run `sockstat -4 | more` as described [here](http://www.freenas.org/images/resources/freenas8.3.0/freenas8.3_guide.html#11.1%20Iperf|outline), there should be a line containing `*:445`. You did set a default gateway? You didn't mess with pfsense? There's no firewall in the way?

Comment: The line exists, what's the problem?I didn't modify any NAS Settings.

http://imgur.com/BrFfRY8